# Possible to do a MYSQL UPDATE query but not actually update a column?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

Is it possible to do an UPDATE query but not actually update a value and leave it alone?

I would like to have queries like this:

```
UPDATE homes SET age = 25, SET name = (don’t update) WHERE id = 1.
```

Of course I could just leave out "SET name =", but I am using this as part of prepared statements in PHP.
The query is first prepared and then queries that match it are sent. But I frequently want to not set a value, but not begin yet another prepared query. Here is an example of my use case

```
$figures = [ ['age' => 'foo1', 'name' => 'DO NOT UPDATE'],   ['age' => 'foo1', 'name' => 'bar1'],   ['age' => 'foo2', 'name' => 'bar2']];

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE homes SET age = ?, name = ?");

foreach ($figures as $row) {
$stmt->execute([$row['age'], $row['name']]);
}
```

The query and the data values can be changed. I'd like to use a single UPDATE prepared statement instead of doing 100s of different prepared statements with a different prepare() for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have specific values for each column that will never appear in the data, you can check for those.  For instance, if name can never be `DO NOT UPDATE`, have your prepared statement be:

```
UPDATE homes SET ..., name = if(?='DO NOT UPDATE',name,?) WHERE id=?
```

and pass the value for name (which may be `DO NOT UPDATE`) to execute twice:

```
$stmt2->execute([..., $row['name'], $row['name'], $row['id']]);
```

Comment: This is what I was hoping to do, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you do not want to separately process the $figures array so you want to do it in a single loop.

So just add a second sql prepared statement (you do not mind, right?) and then use a if-then-else to determine which prepared statement to execute

```
<?php

$figures = [ ['age' => 'foo1', 'name' => 'DO NOT UPDATE', 'id' => '1'],   ['age' => 'foo1', 'name' => 'bar1', 'id' => '2'],   ['age' => 'foo2', 'name' => 'bar2', 'id' => '3']];

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE homes SET age = ?, name = ? where id=?");
$stmt2 = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE homes SET age = ? where id=?");

foreach ($figures as $row) {

 if ($row['name']!='DO NOT UPDATE'){
    $stmt->execute([$row['age'], $row['name'], $row['id']]);
    } else {
     $stmt2->execute([$row['age'], $row['id']]);
  }
}
?>
```

Please amend the prepared statements to suit your real needs

Comment: Using several prepared statements will certainly help on some situations I was thinking of doing this. Thanks.