# Possible datatype error when using INSERT INTO, ON DUPLICATE KEY and IF() in a prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, mysql-8.0

I am trying to send a kind of notification to not update a field during an INSERT INTO, ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE query, which I outlined in this post. ([Possible to do a MYSQL UPDATE query but not actually update a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74418132/possible-to-do-a-mysql-update-query-but-not-actually-update-a-column))

I am following this model which was kindly provided as a reply to that post. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/74418601)

```
UPDATE homes SET ..., name = if(?='DO NOT UPDATE',name,?) WHERE id=?
$stmt2->execute([..., $row['name'], $row['name'], $row['id']]);
```

The problem is that it appears (not certain) that there are type errors in my own go at following this model.

```
$stmt = "INSERT INTO user (id, state, age) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?),(?, ?, ?) AS foo_baz
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
name = if(foo_baz.name='DO NOT UPDATE', user.name, foo_baz.name),
age = if(foo_baz.age='DO NOT UPDATE', user.age, foo_baz.age)";

$data = [1, 'Oregon', 55, 2, 'Washington', 'DO NOT UPDATE'];

$sql = $pdo->prepare($stmt);
$sql->execute($data);
```

The datatypes of the id column is signed int, the state column is varchar, and age is signed int.

When I run this it says

```
"Invalid datetime format: 1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: " for the age column
```

This is probably because 'DO NOT UPDATE' is being placed into an int column, age.

The INSERT INTO, ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is ONLY being used as a way update. All of the data being inserted already has a row with the primary key already existing, so there are no actual inserts. If it were an actual insert, the error would make sense, since it would be trying to insert the wrong datatype into a field. But since it is only updating, the data is not actually inserted (because it is 'DO NOT UPDATE'). I read that mysql tries to insert and then update internally when doing a INSERT INTO, ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE query.

I did try casting the variable but the error repeated itself because the error is probably given in the INSERT part of the query, before the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE part of the query. (This probably would not even work, since 'DO NOT UPDATE' is not an int, and might always give a false negative or positive.)

```
age = if(foo_baz.age=CAST('DO NOT UPDATE' AS SIGNED), user.age, foo_baz.age)
```

If I am interpreting the error correctly (not certain), what I want to accomplish is a technique to put something (doesn't have to be DO NOT UPDATE) into $data for values that I do not want it to update, and have a way to indicate that for ANY datatype column, so any suggestion on how to fix what I have done or accomplish this in another way would be helpful as long as I can do it in the context of an INSERT INTO, ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE query.

Comment: Why not  use `NULL` instead of `'DO NOT UPDATE'`? It can fit in any datatype.

Comment: I think the error is happening for the rows that are being inserted, not the rows that are being updated. If you have `DO NOT UPDATE` for the new age, and there isn't a row, it will try to put `DO NOT UPDATE` into that column.

Comment: I need to sometimes set a value to null, so something else is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to accomplish the same thing (using the sql if() to determine what value(s) to update) as in the previous related post, please change the following

```
$stmt = "INSERT INTO user (id, state, age) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?),(?, ?, ?) AS foo_baz
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
......
```

to

```
$stmt = "INSERT INTO user (id, state, age) 
VALUES (?, ?,  if(?='DO NOT UPDATE',age,?)),(?, ?,  if(?='DO NOT UPDATE',age,?)) AS foo_baz
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
......
```

and make sure you pass the value for age (which may be DO NOT UPDATE) to execute **twice** for each record

So change from

```
$data = [1, 'Oregon', 55, 2, 'Washington', 'DO NOT UPDATE'];
```

to

```
$data = [1, 'Oregon', 55, 55, 2, 'Washington', 'DO NOT UPDATE', 'DO NOT UPDATE'];
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried your example and it worked exactly as intended. The problem I encountered next is that it doesn't scale well for hundreds of rows/values being updated in terms of the amount of data sent to mysql. The real data I work on has 30+ columns and probably will have at least 300 rows updated at a time. If all placeholder values in a tuple (?, ?, ?) must be wrapped in an IF function repeating the column name, that's a very large query to send.

Comment: This may be unavoidable, but any more suggestions would be helpful. I am pretty new to database work in general so I may be missing something obvious like the ability to automatically apply a function to every placeholder, or apply a function to every placeholder or value in a single tuple. I couldn't find a way to do this or further economize.

Comment: Yes wrapping `if function(s)` for the column names will make the query string quite long . Alternatively  you may refer to my suggestion in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74418132/possible-to-do-a-mysql-update-query-but-not-actually-update-a-column/74418601#74418601) to separate the query into two (or more) queries so it is more manageable. Use any one method which suits your needs

Comment: I encountered a bigger issue while implementing that I missed. I don't know how to refer to the current value in the IF statement you suggested. `IF(?='DNT', age, ?)` returns a null value for age. I tried `user.age` and also received null return. It could not reference the current value. What should the IF statement look like to reference the current value?

Comment: pls open a new question so that we can further answer it. thanks

Comment: Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74522567/referring-to-the-current-field-value-in-the-insert-part-of-insert-on-duplicate. Thanks.