# Referring to the current field value in the INSERT part of INSERT, ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement, mysql-8.0

When doing an INSERT statement with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is there a way to refer to the current value of a row and field, when it exists, in the VALUES part of the insert statement? I don't want to refer to it in the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE section.

In my use case, all rows will always exist.

Something like this

```
INSERT INTO  myTable (Col1, Col2) VALUES
('value', myTable.Col2),
('value2', myTable.Col2)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
…
```

I tried this and it nulled all the columns in testing, probably because the reference failed and it returned null instead.

It may be germane to remark that I am trying to do this as part of adding an IF function to an INSERT, ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE query with prepared placeholders. So the final version will be like this:

```
INSERT INTO  myTable (Col1, Col2) VALUES
('value', IF(?='test', myTable.Col2, ?),
('value2', myTable.Col2)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
…
```

Comment: If the rows will always exist, just use `UPDATE`.

Comment: I am working with some constraints here, so I can't use a simple UPDATE query in this case.
I am also trying to avoid multiqueries for security reasons. But a multiquery (with thousands of individual UPDATEs) was almost 20x slower for me than the equivalent INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE way of doing things (where each column had a defined, not referenced, value).

Any tips on resolving this as it is would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can't refer to the current value of the row in the VALUES clause of an INSERT. You'll have to refer to the current value of the row in the ON DUPLICATE UPDATE clause.

For example, you could set the value to NULL in the values clause if your input

```
INSERT INTO  myTable (Col1, Col2) VALUES
('value', NULLIF(?, 'test')), -- default to current value if you insert 'test'
('value2', NULL) -- default to current value always
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
 Col2 = COALESCE(Col2, VALUES(Col2));
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a very interesting idea, but in my testing it I was not able to set a field to null if the original value was not null. The COALESCE would always pick the not null value. Is there a way to allow this to set a null value?

Comment: I originally tried `Col2 = IF('value'='DO NOT UPDATE, Col2, 'newValue')` in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` part, but it did not work because if I set an integer column to 'DO NOT UPDATE' (even with no intent of setting that value) in the `INSERT` part, I would get a type error. (post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74496019/possible-datatype-error-when-using-insert-into-on-duplicate-key-and) The next step was to try the same in the `INSERT` part `IF('value'='DO NOT UPDATE, Col2, 'newValue')` but `Col2` (and `myTable.Col2`) always returns null. I cannot refer to current value of the field.

Comment: This is a good example of why SQL questions on Stack Overflow should include the DDL for the table, so we don't have to guess at your data types and constraints. Good luck!

Comment: If your idea had allowed me to set NULLs, I could have adapted it my own constraints, like datatypes, without additional help, so I did not want to ask more than was required. (I did not think the ability to set NULLs needed to be specified since it is a normal datatype.) I will make a new post with my DDL and full constraints. Thanks.